# IPPROTO_IP vs IPPROTO_TCP/IPPROTO_UDP

Tags: sockets, ip

I'm having some trouble finding documentation on what the distinction between these settings for the third argument to `socket` is. I know about TCP and UDP and their differences and also that IP is one layer up (down?) on the stack... My UDP code seems to work the same whether I set it to `IPPROTO_IP` or `IPPROTO_UDP`.

Comment: Related: [What is `SOCK_DGRAM` and `SOCK_STREAM`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5815675/4561887) and [when is `IPPROTO_UDP` required?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1955198/4561887)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Documentation for `socket()` on Linux is split between various manpages including `ip(7)` that specifies that you have to use `0` or `IPPROTO_UDP` for UDP and `0` or `IPPROTO_TCP` for TCP. When you use `0`, which happens to be the value of `IPPROTO_IP`, UDP is used for `SOCK_DGRAM` and TCP is used for `SOCK_STREAM`.

In my opinion the clean way to create a UDP or a TCP IPv4 socket object is as follows:

```
int sock_udp = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
int sock_tcp = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
```

The reason is that it is generally better to be explicit than implicit. In this specific case using `0` or worse `IPPROTO_IP` for the third argument doesn't gain you anything.

Also imagine using a protocol that can do both streams and datagrams like *sctp*. By always specifying both *socktype* and *protocol* you are safe from any ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

From the `socket(2)` Linux manual page, from `man-pages` 5.08:

> Normally only a single protocol exists to support a
> particular socket type within a given protocol family, in which case
> protocol can be specified as 0.  However, it is possible that many
> protocols may exist, in which case a particular protocol must be
> specified in this manner.

`IPPROTO_IP` is just the usual placeholder constant from the `IPPROTO_`* family with the value `0` in the [socket API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) since [its early days](http://www.retro11.de/ouxr/43bsd/usr/src/sys/netinet/in.h.html).

Of course in the interest of forward compatibility, in case more socket types are added for the protocol family in the future, which could break `0` with UDP/TCP or change its behaviour, it would be best to look up the specific protocol value for the protocol you want and use it, rather than using `0` or `IPPROTO_IP`.

Note that the `IPPROTO_`* header values serve multiple purposes in different contexts: in addition to being used as parameter values to identify protocols here in the socket API and internally in its implementation code, they are also used as the values of the IP protocol field in the IP packets themselves. These IP protocol values, or [*protocol numbers* in IANA terminology](https://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xhtml), themselves have an additional purpose, [identifying different extension header types in IPv6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8200#section-4). This is why `0` is also `IPPROTO_HOPOPTS`, the identifier for the IPv6 Hop-by-Hop Option extension header.