# Sockets - IPPPROTO_TCP Vs. 0

Tags: c++, c, sockets, unix

What's the difference under the covers between using:

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
```

and

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

I had a reason to use a stream socket within an application and was told to use the 2nd one (which I'm guessing is because TCP would be overkill since its in-box and reliable by default).  I wasn't quite sure what the socket created with a null final parameter actually was though, so I'm hesitant to use it.

Comment: Probably this [post][1] helps.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385312/ipproto-ip-vs-ipproto-tcp-ipproto-udp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference. Both will return a TCP socket, because TCP is the default STREAM protocol of INET family.

Answer (score 3):

[`socket()` reference:](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/socket.html)

> Specifying a *protocol* of 0 causes *socket*() to use an unspecified
>   default protocol appropriate for the requested socket type.

Default protocol for a stream socket is naturally TCP. So, to answer your question, there is no difference.