# What is SOCK_DGRAM and SOCK_STREAM?

Tags: c++, sockets, protocols, tcp

I just came across this strange thing I got to see  application is that by default they use `SOCK_STREAM` function.  Why is it so? Is this `SOCK_STREAM` just creating multiple streams? Or is it the standard `SOCK_STREAM` function available for creating TCP stream(s)?

I thought tsunami is based on UDP, but still having some features like that of TCP, e.g. TCP fairness, friendlyness, etc.

Could somebody please shed some light on this issue? I am totally confused over this.

Comment: They are not functions, they are manifest constants to be provided to the `socket()` system call in accordance with its documentation.

Comment: Related: [when is `IPPROTO_UDP` required?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1955198/4561887) and [`IPPROTO_IP` vs `IPPROTO_TCP`/`IPPROTO_UDP`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5385312/4561887)

Answer (score 121):

TCP almost always uses `SOCK_STREAM` and UDP uses `SOCK_DGRAM`.

TCP (`SOCK_STREAM`) is a connection-based protocol.  The connection is established and the two parties have a conversation until the connection is terminated by one of the parties or by a network error.

UDP (`SOCK_DGRAM`) is a datagram-based protocol.  You send one datagram and get one reply and then the connection terminates.

- If you send multiple packets, TCP promises to deliver them in order. 
  UDP does not, so the receiver needs to check them, if the order
  matters.
- If a TCP packet is lost, the sender can tell.  Not so for UDP.
- UDP datagrams are limited in size, from memory I think it is 512
  bytes.  TCP can send much bigger lumps than that.
- TCP is a bit more robust and makes more checks.  UDP is a shade
  lighter weight (less computer and network stress).

Choose the protocol appropriate for how you want to interact with the other computer.

Comment: I use an IP stack from EMBOS. I created a socket of type SOCK_DGRAM. But the select function is getting invoked only the very first time when I recieve a UDP packet....Is there something to do with the socket type in this case?

Comment: @GinuJacob - I don't know anything about EMBOS.  Create a new question and select tags (such as "EMBOS") that will attract people with the right skills to help you.

Comment: UDP/SOCK_DGRAM is a datagram-based protocol, that involves NO connection.  You send any number of datagrams and receive any number of datagrams.  It's an "unreliable service".

Comment: TCP/SOCK_STREAM is a "reliable" or "confirmed" service, in that packets are delivered, in order, or the connection terminates.  The guarantee is that you get notified if the data might not have been delivered.

Comment: What do you mean 'almost'? When *doesn't* TCP use SOCK_STREAM? You go on to imply that they are synonyrmous. You need to clarify. The sender cannot tell whether a TCP packet is lost other than via a connection reset. And there is no connection at all in UDP, or any necessary reply, let alone a connection termination after exactly one send and one response. Answer is largely nonsense.

Comment: @JeffLearman Not true actually, UDP is only limited (as a protocol) to 2^16 bytes. You can send very large UDP packets using IP fragmentation regardless of the MTU and the kernel will reassemble them for you

Comment: @Allison Of course you're right.  No idea what got in my head when I wrote that.  deleted my comment.  Thanks.

Comment: UDP packets are not limited to 512 bytes.  They're limited by UDP to 64K bytes.  They're also limited to the max service data unit size of the network layer.  For IPv4 with fragmentation enabled, this is nearly 64KB.  For IPv4 with fragmentation disabled or IPv6, one should use MTU path discovery, especially if using IP packets larger than 1500 bytes.

Answer (score 83):

One of the ideas behind the **[Berkley Sockets API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets)** was that it could use different **[protocol families](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets#Protocol_and_address_families)** - not just the Internet Protocol (IP). But instead you had one API that could handle all kinds of *"address families"*, e.g.:

- Internet Protocol version 4 (IPv4): `AF_INET`
- IPX/SPX: `AF_IPX`
- AppleTalk: `AF_APPLETALK`
- NetBIOS: `AF_NETBIOS`
- Internet Protocol version 6 (IPv6): `AF_INET6`
- Infrared Data Association (IrDA): `AF_IRDA`
- Bluetooth: `AF_BTH`

Each *protocol family* generally has a few similar concepts of how data will be handled on a socket:

- sequenced, reliable, two-way, connection-based, byte-streams: `SOCK_STREAM` *(what an IP person would call TCP)*
- connectionless, unreliable, datagrams: `SOCK_DGRAM` *(what an IP person would call UDP)*

Different address families have different terms for these basic concepts:

```
╔═══════════╦══════════════════════════╗
║           ║       Socket Type        ║
║ Address   ╟────────────┬─────────────╢
║ Family    ║ SOCK_DGRAM │ SOCK_STREAM ║ 
╠═══════════╬════════════╪═════════════╣
║ IPX/SPX   ║ SPX        │ IPX         ║
║ NetBIOS   ║ NetBIOS    │ n/a         ║
║ IPv4      ║ UDP        │ TCP         ║
║ AppleTalk ║ DDP        │ ADSP        ║
║ IPv6      ║ UDP        │ TCP         ║
║ IrDA      ║ IrLMP      │ IrTTP       ║
║ Bluetooth ║ ?          │ RFCOMM      ║
╚═══════════╩════════════╧═════════════╝
```

The point is:

- If you want reliable, two-way, connection-based, sequenced, byte-streams
- you ask for it using *"SOCK_STREAM"*
- and the **sockets** API will worry about figuring out that you want TCP

Similarly, if i were creating a socket over Infrared (IrDA, `AF_IRDA`):

- i have no idea what protocol in **IrDA** is reliable, sequenced, and connection-based
- all i know is that i want ***something*** that is reliable, sequence, and connection-based

So you say:

```
socket(AF_IRDA, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

And Sockets will figure it out for me.

## Bonus

Originally there was only the two protocol options:

- connectionless, unreliable, datagrams (`SOCK_DGRAM`)
- connection-based, reliable, sequenced, two-way (`SOCK_STREAM`)

Later other protocol choices were added:

- a reliable message datagram (`SOCK_RDM` - *"Reliable Datagram Multicast"* - obsolete; do not use in new programs)
- pseudo-stream sequenced packets based on datagrams (`SOCK_SEQPACKET`)

```
╔═══════════╦══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║           ║                      Socket Type                     ║
║ Address   ╟────────────┬─────────────┬──────────┬────────────────╢
║ Family    ║ SOCK_DGRAM │ SOCK_STREAM │ SOCK_RDM │ SOCK_SEQPACKET ║ 
╠═══════════╬════════════╪═════════════╪══════════╪════════════════╣
║ IPX/SPX   ║ SPX        │ IPX         │ ?        │ ?              ║
║ NetBIOS   ║ NetBIOS    │ n/a         │ ?        │ ?              ║
║ IPv4      ║ UDP        │ TCP         │ ?        │ SCTP           ║
║ AppleTalk ║ DDP        │ ADSP        │ ?        │ ?              ║
║ IPv6      ║ UDP        │ TCP         │ ?        │ SCTP           ║
║ IrDA      ║ IrLMP      │ IrTTP       │ ?        │ ?              ║
║ Bluetooth ║ ?          │ RFCOMM      │ ?        │ ?              ║
╚═══════════╩════════════╧═════════════╧══════════╧════════════════╝
```

It's not guaranteed that any given address family will support such protocol choices; but some do.

### Bonus Bonus Chatter

Hopefully now you see why it is redundant to pass `IPPROTO_TCP` protocol in your call to create a socket:

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); // passing IPPROTO_TCP is redundant
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);           // better
```

You already said you wanted a `SOCK_STREAM`. You don't need to force `TCP` on top of it. In the same way it's redundant to call:

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP); //passing IPPROTO_UDP is redundant
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);           // better
```

***tl;dr:*** It's a protocol-independent way of asking for TCP or UDP. But since nobody on the planet uses AppleTalk, IPX/SPX, IrDA, Bluetooth, NetBIOS anymore, it's mostly vestigial.

Comment: I see no reason why this should not be the most accepted answer

Comment: @ArkestMust Your comment lacks relevance. TCP spans the globe. Bluetooth spans about 100 feet. In any case Bluetooth is a media layer and TCP is a session-layer protocol. There is simply no comparison.

Comment: "*the sockets API will worry about figuring out that you want TCP*" - only when the `protocol` parameter is `0`, ie "use the default `protocol` for the specified `type`".  TCP is the default protocol for `SOCK_STREAM`.  But you can also specify `IPPROTO_TCP` (6) explicitly instead.  Same goes with UDP, which is the default `protocol` for `SOCK_DGRAM` (`IPPROTO_UDP=22`).

Comment: @RemyLebeau What were you workin on that brought you here this evening?

Comment: @IanBoyd what is that supposed to mean?

Comment: @RemyLebeau My answer has been up for a few years now. And i saw your comment 45 minutes after you posted it. And it was in the evening. So i'm curious what got you stumbling across my 2 year old answer on a 10 year old question. Doing some raw socket work? It's genuine curiosity - since we we're both around here a lot.

Comment: @IanBoyd your answer may be 2 years old, but [Gabriel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71417876/65863) is only 1 day old. That triggered this question to show up on my feed, so I made some comments on his answer.  And then I saw your answer, and made some more comments.

Answer (score 8):

**Update:** my answer seems no more relevant, but the original question referred to UDT, which is a connection-oriented protocol built on top of UDP. More info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP-based_Data_Transfer_Protocol

---

UDT appears to provide API which mimics classic BSD sockets API, so it can be used as a drop-in replacement, for both stream and datagram oriented applications. Check e.g. `sendmsg` and `recvmsg` - both throw an exception if used on a socket created with `SOCK_STREAM`, and all the stream oriented APIs throw an exception for socket created with `SOCK_DGRAM` as well.

In case of `SOCK_DGRAM` it  perform some extra processing however, it doesn't simply wrap the UDP socket transparently in such case - as far as I understand the code after a quick review (I'm not familiar with UDT internals or protocol spec). Reading the [technical papers](http://udt.sourceforge.net/doc.html) could help a lot.

The library always creates its underlying, "real" socket as a datagram one (check channel.cpp, `CChannel::open`).

Answer (score 3):

### Preface: useful macros

Here are some useful macros from my go-to socket demo files I wrote for myself, which make it clear how to get *UDP* vs *TCP* packets.

From these files:

1. [socket__geeksforgeeks_udp_server_GS_edit_GREAT.c](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/socket__geeksforgeeks_udp_server_GS_edit_GREAT.c)
2. [socket__geeksforgeeks_udp_client_GS_edit_GREAT.c](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/socket__geeksforgeeks_udp_client_GS_edit_GREAT.c)

...you can find these macros:

```c
// See: https://linux.die.net/man/7/ip
// AF = "Address Family"
// INET = "Internet"
// AF_INET = IPv4 internet protocols
// AF_INET6 = IPv6 internet protocols; see: https://linux.die.net/man/2/socket
// DGRAM = "Datagram" (UDP)
//
// IPv4
#define SOCKET_TYPE_TCP_IPV4              AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0
#define SOCKET_TYPE_UDP_IPV4              AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0
#define SOCKET_TYPE_RAW_IPV4(protocol)    AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, (protocol)
// IPv6
#define SOCKET_TYPE_TCP_IPV6              AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0
#define SOCKET_TYPE_UDP_IPV6              AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0
#define SOCKET_TYPE_RAW_IPV6(protocol)    AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW, (protocol)
```

Usage examples:

```c
int socket_tcp = socket(SOCKET_TYPE_TCP_IPV4);
int socket_udp = socket(SOCKET_TYPE_UDP_IPV4);
// See also: https://www.binarytides.com/raw-sockets-c-code-linux/
int socket_raw = socket(SOCKET_TYPE_RAW_IPV4(IPPROTO_RAW));
```

---

Now back to the question:

> What is `SOCK_DGRAM` and `SOCK_STREAM`?

### Brief Summary

UDP --(is the protocol utilized by)--> `AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM` or `AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM`
TCP --(is the protocol utilized by)--> `AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM` or `AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM`

Examples: from https://linux.die.net/man/7/ip (or as shown in your terminal man pages by running `man 7 ip`):

> tcp_socket = `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);`
> udp_socket = `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);`
> raw_socket = `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, protocol);`

### Long Summary

Reference the `int socket(AddressFamily, Type, Protocol)` socket creation function documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.1?topic=s-socket-subroutine) and [here](https://linux.die.net/man/2/socket) (can also be viewed by running `man 2 socket`). It allows you to specify these 3 parameters:

1. Address Family
2. Socket Type
3. Protocol

For many if not most use-cases, however, the most-useful options for these parameters are frequently:

1. Address Family: `AF_INET` (for IPv4 addresses) or `AF_INET6` (for IPv6 addresses).
2. Socket Type: `SOCK_DGRAM` or `SOCK_STREAM`.
3. Protocol: just use `0` to allow it to use default protocols, as specified from the documentation link above (emphasis added):

   > *Protocol*: Specifies a particular protocol to be used with the socket. **Specifying the Protocol parameter of `0` causes the socket subroutine to default to the typical protocol for the requested type of returned socket.**
4. **`SOCK_DGRAM`**: if you create your socket with `AF_INET` as

   ```c
   int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)
   ```

   or with `AF_INET6` as

   ```c
   int s = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)
   ```

   ...the socket utilizes the **UDP** protocol by default when the (`AF_INET` or `AF_INET6`) address family and `SOCK_DGRAM` Socket Types are selected.

   1. In the **UNIX Address Family domain (`AF_UNIX`)**: when communicating between *processes running on the same operating system* via the `AF_UNIX` Address Family, this is similar to an inter-process *message queue.*
   2. In the **Internet Address Family domain (`AF_INET` and `AF_INET6`)**: when communicating between *a local process and a process running on a remote host* via the `AF_INET` Address Family, this is "implemented on the User Datagram Protocol/Internet Protocol (UDP/IP) protocol."
5. **`SOCK_STREAM`**: if you create your socket with `AF_INET` as

   ```c
   int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)
   ```

   or with `AF_INET6` as

   ```c
   int s = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0)
   ```

   ...the socket utilizes the **TCP** protocol by default when the (`AF_INET` or `AF_INET6`) address family and `SOCK_STREAM` Socket Types are selected.

   1. In the **UNIX Address Family domain (`AF_UNIX`)**: when communicating between *processes running on the same operating system* via the `AF_UNIX` Address Family, this type of socket "works like a pipe" IPC (Inter-process Communication) mechanism.
   2. In the **Internet Address Family domain (`AF_INET` and `AF_INET6`)**: when communicating between *a local process and a process running on a remote host* via the `AF_INET` Address Family, this is "implemented on the Transmission Control Protocol/Internet Protocol (TCP/IP) protocol."

### Details

*In the explanation below, wherever I (or they, in the quoted sections) use `AF_INET` (for IPv4 addresses), keep in mind you can also use `AF_INET6` (for IPv6 addresses) if you like.*

In socket-based communication, including for sending both UDP/IP and TCP/IP Ethernet data packets back and forth between two running processes on the same computer, or between two separate computers, you must specify both the *Address Family* (these constants begin with `AF_`) and *Socket Type* (these constans begin with `SOCK_`).

The best documentation I have found on sockets, hands-down, is from IBM.com, such as here:

1. `int socket(AddressFamily, Type, Protocol)` function: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.1?topic=s-socket-subroutine
2. Address Families: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.1?topic=domains-address-families and here
3. Socket Types: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.1?topic=protocols-socket-types

For additional information on "Sockets", click the links in the left-hand navigation pane after clicking one of the links above.

Other *excellent* documentation can also be found on linux.die.net, such as [the `ip(7)` page here](https://linux.die.net/man/7/ip).

### Address Family (`AF_`) Domains

From the "Address Families" link above, first, we learn about the various **socket Address Families (AF) domains**, which are a prerequisite to understanding the socket types. Here is that information (emphasis added, and my notes added in square brackets []):

> A socket subroutine that takes an address family (AF) as a parameter can use **`AF_UNIX` (UNIX)**, **`AF_INET` (Internet)**, `AF_NS` (Xerox Network Systems), or `AF_NDD` (Network Device Drivers of the operating sytem) protocol. These *address families* are part of the following **communication domains**:
>
> **UNIX**: Provides socket communication between *processes running on the same operating system* when an address family of `AF_UNIX` is specified. A socket name in the UNIX domain is a string of ASCII characters whose maximum length depends on the machine in use.
>
> **Internet**: Provides socket communication between a *local process and a process running on a remote host* when an address family of `AF_INET` is specified. The Internet domain requires that Transmission Control Protocol/Internet Protocol (**TCP/IP**) be installed on your system. A socket name in the Internet domain is an Internet address, made up of a 32-bit IP address [ex: `192.168.0.1`] and a 16-bit port address [any number from `0` to `65535`; [here is a list of common TCP and UDP port numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers)].
>
> **NDD**: Provides socket communication between a local process and a process running on a remote host when an address family of `AF_NDD` is specified. The NDD domain enables applications to run directly on top of physical networks. This is in contrast to the Internet domain, in which applications run on top of transport protocols such as **TCP**, or **User Datagram Protocol (UDP)**. A socket name in the NDD domain consists of operating system NDD name and a second part that is protocol dependent.
>
> *Communication domains* [ex: `AF_UNIX` or `AF_INET`] are described by a domain data structure that is loadable. *Communication protocols* [ex: `SOCK_DGRAM` (UDP) or `SOCK_STREAM` (TCP)] within a domain are described by a structure that is defined within the system for each protocol implementation configured. When a request is made to create a socket, the system uses the name of the *communication domain* to search linearly the list of configured domains. If the domain is found, the domain's table of supported *protocols* is consulted for a protocol appropriate for the type of socket being created or for a specific *protocol request*. (A wildcard entry may exist for a raw domain.) Should multiple protocol entries satisfy the request, the first is selected.

### Socket Types (`SOCK_`)

From the "Socket Types" link above, we learn about the various "underlying *communication protocols*" (emphasis added, and my notes added in square brackets []):

> Sockets are classified according to communication properties. Processes usually communicate between sockets of the same type. However, if the underlying *communication protocols* support the communication, sockets of different types can communicate.
>
> Each socket has an associated **type**, which describes the semantics of communications using that socket. The **socket type** determines the socket communication properties such as *reliability, ordering, and prevention of duplication of messages*. The basic set of socket types is defined in the `sys/socket.h` file:
>
> ```
> /*Standard socket types */
> #define  SOCK_STREAM             1 /*virtual circuit*/
> #define  SOCK_DGRAM              2 /*datagram*/
> #define  SOCK_RAW                3 /*raw socket*/
> #define  SOCK_RDM                4 /*reliably-delivered message*/
> #define  SOCK_CONN_DGRAM         5 /*connection datagram*/
> ```
>
> Other socket types can be defined.
>
> ##### The operating system supports the following basic set of sockets:
>
> ---
>
> **`SOCK_DGRAM`**: Provides datagrams, which are connectionless messages of a fixed maximum length. This type of socket is generally used for short messages, such as a name server or time server, because the order and reliability of message delivery is not guaranteed.
>
> **In the *UNIX domain* [`AF_UNIX`], the `SOCK_DGRAM` socket type is similar to a *message queue*. In the *Internet domain* [`AF_INET`], the `SOCK_DGRAM` socket type is implemented on the User Datagram Protocol/Internet Protocol (UDP/IP) protocol.**
>
> A datagram socket supports the bidirectional flow of data, which is not sequenced, reliable, or unduplicated. A process receiving messages on a datagram socket may find messages duplicated or in an order different than the order sent. Record boundaries in data, however, are preserved. Datagram sockets closely model the facilities found in many contemporary packet-switched networks.
>
> **`SOCK_STREAM`**: Provides sequenced, two-way byte streams with a transmission mechanism for stream data. This socket type transmits data on a reliable basis, in order, and with out-of-band capabilities.
>
> **In the *UNIX domain* [`AF_UNIX`], the `SOCK_STREAM` socket type works *like a pipe*. In the *Internet domain* [`AF_INET`], the `SOCK_STREAM` socket type is implemented on the Transmission Control Protocol/Internet Protocol (TCP/IP) protocol.**
>
> A stream socket provides for the bidirectional, reliable, sequenced, and unduplicated flow of data without record boundaries. Aside from the bidirectionality of data flow, a pair of connected stream sockets provides an interface nearly identical to pipes.
>
> **`SOCK_RAW`**: Provides access to internal network protocols and interfaces. This type of socket is available only to users with root-user authority, or to non-root users who have the `CAP_NUMA_ATTACH` capability. (For non-root raw socket access, the [`chuser`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ssw_aix_71/c_commands/chuser.html) command assigns the `CAP_NUMA_ATTACH` capability, along with `CAP_PROPAGATE`. For further information, refer to the `chuser` command.)
>
> Raw sockets allow an application to have direct access to lower-level communication protocols. Raw sockets are intended for advanced users who want to take advantage of some protocol feature that is not directly accessible through a normal interface, or who want to build new protocols on top of existing low-level protocols.
>
> Raw sockets are normally datagram-oriented, though their exact characteristics are dependent on the interface provided by the protocol.
>
> **`SOCK_SEQPACKET`**: Provides sequenced, reliable, and unduplicated flow of information.
>
> **`SOCK_CONN_DGRAM`**: Provides connection-oriented datagram service. This type of socket supports the bidirectional flow of data, which is sequenced and unduplicated, but is not reliable. Because this is a connection-oriented service, the socket must be connected prior to data transfer. Currently, only the Asynchronous Transfer Mode (ATM) protocol in the Network Device Driver (NDD) domain supports this socket type.

How do they work?

> The `SOCK_DGRAM` and `SOCK_RAW` socket types allow an application program to send datagrams to correspondents named in [`send`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ssw_aix_71/communicationtechref/send.html) subroutines. Application programs can receive datagrams through sockets using the [`recv`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ssw_aix_71/communicationtechref/recv.html) subroutines. The Protocol parameter is important when using the `SOCK_RAW` socket type to communicate with low-level protocols or hardware interfaces. The application program must specify the address family in which the communication takes place.

This is the **general sequence of function calls required to communicate using `SOCK_STREAM` (TCP protocol) socket types:**

> The `SOCK_STREAM` socket types are **full-duplex byte streams**. A stream socket must be connected before any data can be sent or received on it. When using a stream socket for data transfer, an application program needs to perform the following sequence:
>
> 1. Create a connection to another socket with the [`connect`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ssw_aix_71/communicationtechref/connect.html) subroutine.
> 2. Use the [`read`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ssw_aix_71/r_bostechref/read.html) and [`write`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ssw_aix_71/w_bostechref/write.html) subroutines or the [`send`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ssw_aix_71/communicationtechref/send.html) and [`recv`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ssw_aix_71/communicationtechref/recv.html) subroutines to transfer data.
> 3. Use the [`close`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ssw_aix_71/c_bostechref/close.html) subroutine to finish the session.
>
> An application program can use the `send` and `recv` subroutines to manage out-of-band data.

Possible errors returned or set in the `errno` variable when using `SOCK_STREAM`:

> `SOCK_STREAM` communication protocols are designed to prevent the loss or duplication of data. If a piece of data for which the peer protocol has buffer space cannot be successfully transmitted within a reasonable period of time, the connection is broken. When this occurs, the [socket](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ssw_aix_71/communicationtechref/socket.html) subroutine indicates an error with a return value of `-1` and the `errno` global variable is set to `ETIMEDOUT`. If a process sends on a broken stream, a `SIGPIPE` signal is raised. Processes that cannot handle the signal terminate. When out-of-band data arrives on a socket, a `SIGURG` signal is sent to the process group.
>
> The process group associated with a socket can be read or set by either the `SIOCGPGRP` or `SIOCSPGRP` `ioctl` operation. To receive a signal on any data, use both the `SIOCSPGRP` and `FIOASYNC` `ioctl` operations. These operations are defined in the `sys/ioctl.h` file.

That about covers it. I hope to write some basic demos in my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo in the [`c` dir](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/tree/master/c) soon.

### Main References:

1. [my answer] [What does the number in parentheses shown after Unix command names in manpages mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58496243/4561887)
2. *****https://linux.die.net/man/7/ip
3. https://linux.die.net/man/2/socket
4. https://linux.die.net/man/7/tcp
5. https://linux.die.net/man/7/udp
6. `int socket(AddressFamily, Type, Protocol)` function: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.1?topic=s-socket-subroutine
7. Address Families: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.1?topic=domains-address-families and here
8. Socket Types: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.1?topic=protocols-socket-types

### Related:

1. [What is `SOCK_DGRAM` and `SOCK_STREAM`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5815675/4561887)
2. [when is `IPPROTO_UDP` required?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1955198/4561887)
3. [`IPPROTO_IP` vs `IPPROTO_TCP`/`IPPROTO_UDP`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5385312/4561887)

Comment: "*`SOCK_DGRAM` is UDP... `SOCK_STREAM` is TCP*" - that is incorrect on both counts. `SOCK_DGRAM` is a datagram-oriented socket, regardless of the transport protocol used.  UDP is one, but not the only, transport that uses datagrams. `SOCK_STREAM` is a stream-oriented socket, regardless of the transport protocol used. TCP is one, but not the only, transport that uses streams.  The `protocol` parameter of `socket()` dictates whether UDP/TCP is used, not the `type` parameter. But UDP can only be used on a `SOCK_DGRAM` type socket, and TCP can only be used on a `SOCK_STREAM` type socket.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, what if I change it to: "`SOCK_DGRAM` utilizes the UDP protocol when the `AF_INET` address family domain is selected"?

Comment: That would also be incorrect, since UDP and TCP both also support `AF_INET6`. The address family dictates how peers are addressed (IPv4 vs IPv6 vs ...), not related to the type of the socket (datagram vs stream vs ...), or the protocol used (UDP vs TCP vs ...). UDP is used only when the socket protocol is explicitly `IPPROTO_UDP`. TCP is used only when the socket protocol is explicitly `IPPROTO_TCP`. Other transports are possible (ICMP, IPX, RAW, etc).

Comment: @RemyLebeau, let me work on it. I'm new to `socket`s. Lots to absorb here.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I'm really trying to get this right. How about now?

Comment: It is still a bit misleading.  You really need to differentiate between the *type* of the socket, and the *protocol* the socket uses.  `socket()` makes that distinction.  Your explain doesn't, not very well anyway.  And you are still completely ignoring that `AF_INET6` exists for IPv6 addressing. `AF_INET` is for IPv4 addressing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242791/discussion-between-gabriel-staples-and-remy-lebeau).

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I updated the answer a bunch again, FYI, per your comments.

Comment: "TCP is a default protocol utilized by `SOCK_STREAM`" is nonsensical. `SOCK_STREAM` is just a selector constant for an API. The API has no notion of "default for `SOCK_STREAM` or `SOCK_DGRAM`". Maybe in case of `AF_X` + `SOCK_Y` you could speak in terms of defaults, but that misses the point of the question.

Comment: @BłażejMichalik, I feel like this is a case of pedantic people arguing about both English semantics and Berkely sockets API semantics simultaneously. Perhaps "de facto standad" is a more-appropriate term than "default", to a pedantic, since no notion of "default" exists in the Berkely sockets contract, but rather only exists in the implementation of it?--all of which use the defaults as I stated in my brief summary? Anyway, I'm not sure what else to say about this other than I feel it is a case of pedantics arguing about pedantry.

Comment: No, because the point of these selectors is that the API makes the choice based on `AF`/`SOCK` matrix. Saying "it's a default for `SOCK_XYZ`" perpetuates a fallacious idea, that there is a default for a `SOCK_*` in the absence of `AF_*`.

Comment: @BłażejMichalik, I updated the top of my answer. I see that address family `AF_*` and `SOCK_*` must be bound as a pair. I've never seen anything used in the first parameter _other than_ `AF_INET` or `AF_INET6`, but my socket experience is limited, and I get the impression that this interface was developed when the industry standards were still very much in-flux and evolving, and eventually the industry settled on the common usages we see today.