# What is the function of SOCK_STREAM?

Tags: python, sockets, python-sockets

I am learning about sockets in Python and came up with

```
variable = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

I understood the function of this `socket.socket` and `socket.AF_INET` but I am curious about `socket.SOCK_STREAM`. What is its function?

Answer (score 47):

`SOCK_STREAM` means that it is a TCP socket.

`SOCK_DGRAM` means that it is a UDP socket.

These are used 99% of the time. There are other possibilities as well, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.SOCK_STREAM (you will have to google for the meaning of each one).

Comment: Is there a reason why they didn't just name it SOCK_TCP and SOCK_UDP?

Comment: @Rockstar5645 generally tcp/udp is sock_stream/dgram over ip4/6. But sock_stream/dgram can mean other things, see this, third answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815675/what-is-sock-dgram-and-sock-stream/10810040 But typically, like 99% of time it will be tcp/udp.

Comment: @Rockstar5645
Just saw this and thought through it.
The other reason which SOCK_STREAM & SOCK_DGRAM is used instead of SOCK_TCP & SOCK_UDP is that there is nothing like SOCK_TCP & SOCK_UDP.
SOCK_STREAM is used to create a stream of sockets and enable TCP connections.

Answer (score 9):

`SOCK_STREAM` is a constant indicating the type of socket (TCP), as opposed to `SOCK_DGRAM` (UDP).

Answer (score 5):

The `SOCK_STREAM` means connection-oriented TCP protocol.

Comment: this is what I was looking for. Thanks.