# Connect python local server with godot

Tags: python, godot, gdscript

I'm trying to send data to a python server:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('127.0.0.1',6000))

s.listen(5)

while True:
    clientsocket,address = s.accept()
    print(f"Got connection from {address} !")
```

from godot:

```
var socket = PacketPeerUDP.new()
socket.set_dest_address("127.0.0.1",6000)
socket.put_packet("quit".to_ascii())
```

based on this [link](https://gamefromscratch.com/godot-3-tutorial-networking/)

but it doesn't seem to be working, How do I send the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm not that familiar with python servers, but it looks like you have a python server that listens for TCP connections but in godot you connect via UDP Client.

As seen in this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35725838/4423341) SOCK_STREAM is for TCP Server and SOCK_DGRAM for UDP.

I am not sure which of those you want to use. An example server for UDP would be:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(('127.0.0.1',6000))
bufferSize  = 1024

#s.listen(5)
print("running")
while True:
    bytesAddressPair = s.recvfrom(bufferSize)
    message = bytesAddressPair[0]
    clientMsg = "Message from Client:{}".format(message)
    print(clientMsg)
```

I copied most of it from here : [Sample UDP Server](https://pythontic.com/modules/socket/udp-client-server-example)

If you wanted to have a TCP Server you should alter the Godot part to use a TCP Client. See the official docs [here](https://docs.godotengine.org/de/stable/classes/class_streampeertcp.html)

Answer (score 1):

figured it out thanks to @René Kling 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72828420/18005234)

**just incase someone wants the complete version**

python server:

```
import socket

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 6000

s= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))

while True:
    message, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    print(f"Connected by {addr}")
```

Godot:

```
extends Node2D
tool

export(bool) var btn =false setget set_btn

var socket = PacketPeerUDP.new()


func set_btn(new_val):
    socket.set_dest_address("127.0.0.1", 6000)
    socket.put_packet("Time to stop".to_ascii())
```