# What is the point of specifying SOCK_STREAM and IPPROTO_TCP in getaddrinfo if both refer to a TCP connection?

Tags: c++, c, winsock, winsock2

I'm revisiting winsock after all these years with fresh eyes and can't seem to understand why `SOCK_STREAM` and `IPPROTO_TCP` are both necessary to specify in the `pHints` parameter of [getaddrinfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfo):

```
INT WSAAPI getaddrinfo(
  [in, optional] PCSTR           pNodeName,
  [in, optional] PCSTR           pServiceName,
  [in, optional] const ADDRINFOA *pHints,
  [out]          PADDRINFOA      *ppResult
);
```

Reading through MSDN's documentation on [addrinfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2def/ns-ws2def-addrinfoa) also doesn't seem to shed much light.

In that article is a table with possible `SOCK_` type definitions and it has this to say in the *meaning* of `SOCK_STREAM`.

> Provides sequenced, reliable, two-way, connection-based byte streams
> with an OOB data transmission mechanism. **Uses the Transmission Control
> Protocol (TCP)** for the Internet address family (AF_INET or AF_INET6).
> If the ai_family member is AF_IRDA, then SOCK_STREAM is the only
> supported socket type.

What's the purpose of separating socket type and protocol if it seems one necessitates the other, and from what I can tell, aren't interchangeable among other protocols and socket types?

Is this for legacy purposes? Something vestigial in nature? Thanks.

EDIT: To further my point [addrinfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2def/ns-ws2def-addrinfoa) also defines `IPPROTO_TCP` in this manner.

> The Transmission Control Protocol (TCP). This is **a possible value when**
> the ai_family member is AF_INET or AF_INET6 and **the ai_socktype member**
> **is SOCK_STREAM**.

EDIT2: After some nudging in the right direction thanks to comments it would seem there are a handful of protocols that utilize stream sockets: RSVP, RDP, X.25, TCP, and SCTP.

But, from what I have been able to read into thus far, a stream socket and TCP itself both guarantee the same connection *characteristics* if you will. Both are reliable, have error checking, support full-duplex communication, etc. The definitions seem indistinguishable to me. It makes me question whether or not TCP is in it's most fundamental form just a vanilla protocol stealing the spotlight from sock stream.

I seriously can't seem to grasp the difference between the two.

Comment: Because SCTP also exists, and the API designers wisely foresaw other reliable transports. OSI has four.

Comment: Not all stream sockets use TCP

Comment: lol, from what I remember you can allow the stack to find a suitable protocol for you, IPPROTO_ANY.

Comment: This gets way more understandable for datagram sockets that can support multiple protocols: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4808471/4885321
OK, the answer is Linux-specific and related to datagrams, but please note that: a. the point might have been genericity of the interface b. winsock interface bases on the POSIX one

Comment: See `man 7 unix` for UNIX sockets that can be stream or dgram: ```Valid socket types in the UNIX domain are: SOCK_STREAM, for a stream-oriented socket; SOCK_DGRAM, for a datagram-oriented socket that preserves message boundaries (as on most UNIX implementations, UNIX domain datagram sockets are always reliable  and  don't reorder datagrams)```

Comment: @user207421 Fair enough. In my sleepy 4AM brain I couldn't fathom Microsoft not enumerating all possible protocols that make use of `SOCK_STREAM`. After having looked it up there are a handful that do such as RSVP, SCTP, X.25 and RDP. I guess I assumed basically any reliable, full-duplex protocol just built off of TCP. Thanks.

Comment: Well you can't enumerate them because new ones keep getting invented. SCTP didn't exist in 1982-3 when all this was designed.

Comment: @user207421 I guess what I'm hung up on is that, from what I can tell, TCP and a stream socket both seem to offer the same connection "characteristics" if you will. Both are reliable, full-duplex, have error checking and the sort. I actually have a hard time telling them apart. I think they're even on the same layer in the OSI model. Obviously this probably doesn't matter in practice but I'm just curious is all and I can't find a solid differentiator for the two other than one is labeled as a protocol and the other a socket.

Comment: @EdwardSeverinsen TCP isn't in the OSI model at all, it is in the TCP/IP model. As I said, OSI has *four* reliable transports in the Transport layer, and TCP/IP now has at least two. NB One is labelled as a protocol. the other as a socket *type.*